# Which Type C to USB adapters work with Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I have been given a Macbook Pro A2442 which for some horribly deranged reason, has been manufactured without standard USB 2 or USB 3 ports.

Since the official Apple Type C to USB adapter is pointlessly expensive (and has an ugly design), I'm looking for a more reasonable alternative. The problem is that I see posts of adapters not being compatible or not working due to software issues.  My objective is to connect my (non Apple) mouse via USB and to be able to use pen drives to transfer data.

Is there a known list of adapters that have been tested with Macs and are known to work? This is for purchase in India.

Comment: "some horribly deranged reason" - international law. USB-C is now compulsory on all new devices in the EU. Apple are even being forced to abandon Lightning in favour of USB-C.

Comment: I have two of those Apple adapters - work fine. Like my machine so look after it. I don't buy the cheap chinesium adapters...

Comment: @Tetsujin: It's not yet a law. The deadline is 2026. The law as far as I remember, was for chargers. I don't think anyone stops laptop manufacturers from adding a USB3 port for plugging in a mouse or pen drive. The spirit is to avoid electronic waste. Apple could have easily continued providing a USB2 and USB3 port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a USB-C hub that provides 2 or more USB-A ports -- as well as other things like Ethernet, HDMI, and SD-cards (though you have the last two built-in already.)

There are plenty of hubs that advertise as Mac compatible. I don't think there's any major incompatibility issues; though as ever, the cheaper end of the market will cut corners.

I've used brands like Anker, Ugreen, and Uni.

Also, how lucky to have been been given an MBP!

Comment: Thank you benwiggy. I understand that some people would be happy with a Macbook. It has a good build quality. However, the keyboard functionality and various other aspects of the software and accessories make the Macbook detestable to people like me. It's a pain to use it. Absolutely incredibly annoying. I would have considered myself lucky if I got a Windows laptop on which I could have installed Linux as dual-boot.

Comment: @Nav If it has good build quality, what's wrong with the keyboard? If there are issues you have, perhaps ask a question, as things can be configured. However, coming to a new OS with strict expectations of how it should work (in any direction) tend to cause more friction than working with the software as designed.

Comment: In Linux, a lot of key combos use Ctrl. But in Mac, some of those use Ctrl and some use the Command key. When pressing Ctrl+Command+Q to lock screen, sometimes one of those keys does not get registered, and an app that's in focus closes instead. When I start the Mac, my plugged in headphones don't get detected, and sound comes via the default speakers. There's no Home and PgUp PgDown buttons. Other missing keys. There are various other annoying software issues which make the Mac very unusable. I'd rather not discuss this further. Apple no longer seems to care about delighting customers.